# when using the Text editor the cursor is not visible at all. no blinking either

Tags: cursor

Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, latest update as of Jan 17 2023. once i open the text editor i do not see the cursor. this makes it hard to use the text editor. can someone help me out getting the cursor back. I'm fairly new in Ubuntu, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think you're in dark mode (so white cursor) and you decided to put the text editor with a white background. So you don't see it.